# search filter in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios

how to use search filter: React?

I tried the below method to use `search effect` in reactjs but the result is not coming in my case. I think I have made a silly mistake somewhere, it would be great if anybody could figure out what I'm trying to solve is.

API end-point URL: http://localhost:8000/api/v1/post_list?search=test

```js
function PostListSearch() {
  const [posts, setPost] = useState([]);
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState([]);
  let signal = axios.CancelToken.source();

  function handleChange(event) {
    setUserId(event.target.value);
  }

  function handleClick(event) {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:8000/api/v1/post_list?search=${userId}`, {
        cancelToken: signal.token
      })
      .then(res => {
        const posts = res.data;
        setPost(posts);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div class="theme-layout">
        <div class="topbar stick">
          <div class="top-area">
            <div class="top-search">
              <form>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="search"
                  onChange={handleClick}
                  placeholder="Search keyword"
                />
                <button data-ripple>
                  <i class="ti-search"></i>
                </button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        {posts.map(post => (
          <ul key={post.id}>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-xl-9">
              <img src={post.image} alt="" class="img-fluid" />
              <h3>{post.title}</h3>
            </div>
          </ul>
        ))}
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default PostListSearch;
```

Comment: You were putting `handleClick` function to the input element instead of `handleChange`. See how to turn a form into a controlled component [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

Comment: @Hangindev  yes i made changes before. still i am not getting the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function PostListSearch() {
  const [posts, setPost] = useState([]);
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState([]);
  let signal = axios.CancelToken.source();

  function handleChange(event) {
    setUserId(event.target.value);
  }

  function handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:8000/api/v1/post_list?search=${userId}`, {
        cancelToken: signal.token
      })
      .then(res => {
        const posts = res.data;
        setPost(posts);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div class="theme-layout">
        <div class="topbar stick">
          <div class="top-area">
            <div class="top-search">
              <form>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="search"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  placeholder="Search keyword"
                />
                <button data-ripple onClick={handleClick}>
                  <i class="ti-search"></i>
                </button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        {posts.map(post => (
          <ul key={post.id}>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-xl-9">
              <img src={post.image} alt="" class="img-fluid" />
              <h3>{post.title}</h3>
            </div>
          </ul>
        ))}
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default PostListSearch;
```

try this out bro :D

Comment: where you have made changes?

Comment: i add onclick on button and onchage on input.
search just run when you active button :D

Comment: bro  i'm still getting the result as before.

Comment: i think somewhere value is not passing properly.

Comment: ` const posts = res.data; 
        setPost(posts);` could you show me the `console.log(res.data)`

Comment: it showing me `index.js:1 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.` in console tab

Comment: i think id not exist in your post object :D try `{posts.map((post, index) => (` then use `index` as your `key`

Comment: can you please help me through remote desktop application like teamviewer or anydesk?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217117/discussion-between-bounty-and-anh-tuan).

Comment: sr my company block remote application. can you provide your code in codesanbox or something like that ?

Comment: as per your request, here is the codesandbox for a demo -->  https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-currying-b6q9t

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-kare-krhds?file=/src/App.js check this out bro.
i add event prevent default for submit search , may be your problem is your api :)) i just make a const arr post to prevent that.

Comment: hi there.... your codesandbox is not working properly.... whenever i'm searching `test1` then it's returning all the value, instead of `test1`

Comment: you can take a look at my github repo... if you find any issues then please give me a pull request... https://github.com/hackersbergg/socia-site

Comment: filter logic stay in your sever side :D client side doesnt handle that

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can update your map logic and state initialisation as follows. Just copy paste the code as it is and try with both the approaches I have mentioned.

```
 function PostListSearch() {
  const [posts, setPost] = useState([]);
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState("");  // CHANGE HERE
  let signal = axios.CancelToken.source();

  function handleChange(event) {
    setUserId(event.target.value);
  }

  function handleClick(event) {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:8000/api/v1/post_list?search=${userId}`, {
        cancelToken: signal.token
      })
      .then(res => {
        const posts = res.data;
        setPost(posts);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div class="theme-layout">
        <div class="topbar stick">
          <div class="top-area">
            <div class="top-search">
              <form>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="search"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  placeholder="Search keyword"
                />
                <button data-ripple onClick={handleClick}>
                  <i class="ti-search"></i>
                </button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        {
                    posts.map((post) => {<ul key={post.id}>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-xl-9">
    
                            <img src={post.image} alt="" class="img-fluid" />
                            <h3>{post.title}</h3>
    
                        </div>
                    </ul>})
                }
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default PostListSearch;
```

Another solution could be to keep initialistion as it is and try to push value in array. For this I have done changes in handleChange method

```
function PostListSearch() {
      const [posts, setPost] = useState([]);
      const [userId, setUserId] = useState([]);  
      let signal = axios.CancelToken.source();
    
      function handleChange(event) {
let currUser = userId;
currUser.push(event.target.value)
        setUserId(currUser );
      }
    
      function handleClick(event) {
        axios
          .get(`http://localhost:8000/api/v1/post_list?search=${userId}`, {
            cancelToken: signal.token
          })
          .then(res => {
            const posts = res.data;
            setPost(posts);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      }
    
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <div class="theme-layout">
            <div class="topbar stick">
              <div class="top-area">
                <div class="top-search">
                  <form>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="search"
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      placeholder="Search keyword"
                    />
                    <button data-ripple onClick={handleClick}>
                      <i class="ti-search"></i>
                    </button>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    
          <div class="row">
            {
                        posts.map((post) => {<ul key={post.id}>
                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-xl-9">
        
                                <img src={post.image} alt="" class="img-fluid" />
                                <h3>{post.title}</h3>
        
                            </div>
                        </ul>})
                    }
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
    
    export default PostListSearch;
```

I believe anyone of the above solution should work.

Comment: okay great!! but the result is coming different. for e.g if i'm searching `test-01` then result should come `test-01` only, but instead of i'm getting all the posts in database.

Comment: I have updated the answer to pass the value you entered in textbox. Please try now

Comment: opppsss!! still i'm getting same issue. :(

Comment: Could you console.log(event) and see that are you getting the value of textbox in handleClick function

Comment: it showing me `index.js:1 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. ` in console tab

Comment: do you use any remote desktop application?

Comment: Nopes... I have updated the answer. Please check now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217118/discussion-between-raghvender-kataria-and-bounty).

Comment: I have added 2 approaches in my answer. You can just copy paste the code as it is and see if any of them works out for you